# plus Week with PHP Date with GET?

Tags: php, datetime

I have URL:

http://www.mysite.com/

here is:

```
$date = new DateTime("2011-11-28");
```

this show me:

> 2011-11-28

i would like add for this site buttons PREVIOUS and NEXT.
If i click NEXT then i have url:

http://www.mysite.com/number/2

now this show me:

```
2011-12-05 //(+ 7 days)
```

and i have buttons PREVIOUS (http://www.mysite.com/number/1) and NEXT (http://www.mysite.com/next/3)
etc.

How can i modify

```
$date = new DateTime("2011-11-28");
```

with $_GET['number'] ? i have modify from 2011-11-28 interval 7 day!

Comment: +1 since I think the downvotes were unwarranted and offered in haste with ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [DateTime::modify](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.modify.php) (available in PHP >= 5.2)

What you want to do is:

```
// just for checking if nobody is tampering with the number variable:
if (strcspn($_GET['number'], '0123456789') != strlen($_GET['number']) {
    die('Invalid input!');
}
// actual calculation:
$amountOfDays = ((int)$_GET['number']) * 7;
$date = new DateTime("2011-11-28");
$date->modify('+'.$amountOfDays.' day');
```

Alternatively, you can use [DateTime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.add.php), but that is only defined in PHP versions >= 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`add`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) and [`sub`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) to add/subtract days.

```
$date = new DateTime("2011-11-28");
$num = $_GET['number'];
$interval = new DateInterval('P'.$num.'W');
$date->add($interval);
```

Or, you can use [`modify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

```
$date = new DateTime("2011-11-28");
$num = $_GET['number'];
$date->modify(($num>0 ? '+' : '').$num.' weeks');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at mktime()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

You can convert the primary date to a timestamp and add 7 days:

```
$new_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, (28 + intval($_GET['number'])), 2011);
$visible_date = date('Y-m-d', $new_date);
echo $visible_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$date = new DateTime('@'.strtotime( $_GET['number'] . ' week'));
```

where `$_GET['number']` is a natural number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$days = (intval($_GET['number']) - 1) * 7;
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval("P$daysD"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I like strtotime a lot :)
It works like this:

```
$date = new DateTime("2011-11-28"); 
$prevWeek = strtotime('-1 week',$date);
$nextWeek = strtotime('+1 week',$date);
```

Comment: strtotime is very expensive - there are many more efficient ways to write that